# Moodle 3.4 installation "Open your browser and go to http://IP.ADDRESS.OF.SERVER/moodle" is not working

Tags: moodle

Moodle installation is done successfully but when I am trying to open from browser getting as unable to connect[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWcHB.png)

Comment: Can you show your installation steps guide ? reset your browser cookie and than try it again? does it chrome or Internet explorer ?

Comment: @Sampada Kulkarni please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have already fixed it.
As I see it, you have the server on a separate hardware.

Check that the server and your computer can communicate. Simply ping server IP.

If they are in the same network, check that `Apache` is running. If you have a GUI in your server, try to access `Moodle` locally from the server. If it doesn't work, check `Apache` configuration and make sure it is running.

If `Apache` is running, check your firewall and ports. Try to open port 80 on your server. On `Ubuntu Server`, it is:

```
sudo ufw allow 80  
sudo ufw enable  
sudo ufw reload
```

If you have other Linux distro, google the syntax.

Hope this helps.